# Encoding issue on Chrome and not IE

Tags: exception, encoding, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, linq-to-xml

When creating an XDocument I get an XmlException with the following message:

```
system does not support 'iso-8859-1' encoding line 1, position 31
```

The first line of the Xml document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
```

Here is the code I use to create the document:

```
 xDoc = XDocument.Load(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

The weird thing is that the exception happens on Chrome and Firefox but not IE8.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question exactly? After all, the error message seems relatively clear. Do you need to use iso-8859-1?

Comment: How can I get around this issue? Is there a setting in Chrome that i need to check for? Why is it happening in Chrome an not IE8? Am I doing/not doing something when loading the document that is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers do not support this encoding. Basically, you can install a font for whatever language you're trying to display (I'm assuming this is why you're using that encoding). Then, you can embed that font for use on any local machine.

- code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31510
- bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22339

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing similar behavior when downloading an xml doc that is generated by a .NET web service for OData (served locally by IIS 7).  It shows up with different content types based on browser.  Both the content-type header as well as the first line of the xml file is changing.  Putting a breakpoint in and inspecting the "HttpWebResponse" object or using Fiddler shows:

```
content-type: "application/xml;charset=utf-8"         (IE)
content-type: "application/xml;charset=iso-8859-1"    (Chrome)
```

Comparing at first line of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>      (IE)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?> (Chrome)
```

This is resulting in the default XDocument.Load(webResponse_stream) to fail on Chrome.